# Add ID to parent Iframe youtube

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, youtube

I need to add a class.

Like this :

```
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/">
</iframe>
```

To

```
<div class="video-class">
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Go for it! What's your question?

Comment: How to add class to parent Iframe

Comment: You did it in your question. Are you looking to do it automatically, on something like user-provided input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap an element with another element using jQuery's [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.  For example:

```js
$('iframe').wrap($('<div>', { 'class': 'video-class' }));
```

```css
.video-class {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/">
</iframe>
```

(Styling added to demonstrate the wrapped element, though you can also examine the DOM in your browser's development tools.)